# I'm using Pry, specifically Remote-Pry, and when in console, I press back, an "Exit" prompts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, pry, pry-rails

So regardless of my console history, if I'm in a pry session, and if I press the up stroke, it *should* show what my last command was. Instead, it shows `exit`, and will execute exit if I press enter.

Why does this occur? How can I fix it?